Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'forEach'
Hello everyone, I try to fix my problem code for a while, and it still cannot fix it
let add_room_form = document.getElementById('add_room_form');
    add_room_form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        add_rooms();
    });

    function add_rooms() {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('add_room', '');
        data.append('name', add_room_form.elements['name'].value);
        data.append('area', add_room_form.elements['area'].value);
        data.append('price', add_room_form.elements['price'].value);
        data.append('quantity', add_room_form.elements['quantity'].value);
        data.append('adult', add_room_form.elements['adult'].value);
        data.append('children', add_room_form.elements['children'].value);
        data.append('desc', add_room_form.elements['desc'].value);

        // Collect features
        let features = [];
        add_room_form.elements['features'].forEach(el => {
            if (el.checked) {
                console.log(el.value);
            }
        })

